# JQuery Mobile showPageLoadingMsg()

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a login page and would like to show the spinner while the web page calls an ajax function to load data, when that is finished it calls chagePage and everything loads fine, except no spinner ever shows.  I got the timeout from the other questions, it works if I'm debugging and stepping through but not live.  I've also tried putting it in the beforeSend of the ajax.

```
$('#loginButton').live('click',function(e){
    $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
    setTimeout(initialLogin(),300);
});
```

Thanks!

```
    if(success){
//Load home page
    $.mobile.changePage("#second");
    loadList(); //loads listview
}
```

FYI here are the settings I'm using

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
$.mobile.defaultPageTransition = 'none';
$.mobile.buttonMarkup.hoverDelay= 250;
$.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
$.support.cors = true;
$.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;
$.mobile.orientationChangeEnabled = true;
});
```

Comment: What is the code for the `initialLogin()` function?

Comment: Just some textbox validation and then it calls the ajax function, when I step through it shows the spinner correctly all the way to the hidePageLoadingMsg() like it's supposed to.  Even if I set the timeout to 5000 it just sits there for 5 seconds and never shows the spinner.

Comment: The reason I want to see the code of the `initialLogin()` function is because you are most likely making this more complicated than it needs to be. The `changePage` function can show/hide the loading message on its own.

Comment: I call changePage later after the ajax, I'll paste that code

Comment: Let me know when you do and I'll check it out.

Comment: It's up now, loadList adds a listItem innerHTML if a variable is met, then does a $(list).listview("refresh");

Comment: Just tried $.mobile.changePage("#second", {showLoadMsg: true}); and removed the other showPageLoadingMsg() call, still no dice.  The docs say it's for external pages though.  All of mine are internal pages.

Answer (score 1):

You can use it application wide like this:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function () {
    $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
}).ajaxStop(function () {
        $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
    });
```

Comment: Still not working as expected, again it doesn't seem to matter where I put it in the chain of events it only appears if I stop during debugging.  Unless the changePage happens really fast and hides it before the page UI refreshes.

Answer (score 0):

It's working fine now, I set the ajax async to true and fill the objects in the success area.